# Pandas - Replace substrings from a column if not numeric

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, substring

I have a list of suffixes I want to remove in a list, say `suffixes = ['inc','co','ltd']`.
I want to remove these from a column in a Pandas dataframe, and I have been doing this:
`df['name'] = df['name'].str.replace('|'.join(suffixes), '')`.

This works, but I do NOT want to remove the suffice if what remains is numeric. For example, if the name is `123 inc`, I don't want to strip the 'inc'. Is there a way to add this condition in the code?

Comment: So for example "Apple inc" turns into "Apple" but "123 inc" remains "123 inc"?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Regex --> `negative lookbehind`.

**Ex:**

```
suffixes = ['inc','co','ltd']

df = pd.DataFrame({"Col": ["Abc inc", "123 inc", "Abc co", "123 co"]})
df['Col_2'] = df['Col'].str.replace(r"(?<!\d) \b(" + '|'.join(suffixes) + r")\b", '', regex=True)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
       Col    Col_2
0  Abc inc      Abc
1  123 inc  123 inc
2   Abc co      Abc
3   123 co   123 co
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `^[^0-9]+` to the suffixes. It is a REGEX that literally means "at least one not numeric char before". The code would look like this:

```py
non_numeric_regex = r"^[^0-9]+"
suffixes = ['inc','co','ltd']
regex_w_suffixes = [non_numeric_regex + suf for suf in suffixes]
df['name'] = df['name'].str.replace('|'.join(regex_w_suffixes ), '')
```

Comment: I copy-pasted this and it still removes the text from the numbers

Comment: Can you share a small example of your data and expected result? otherwise it is hard to refine a regex

Comment: I simply used this to test it. df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['Apple inc','123 inc','ayylmao co','987 co']})